# how to write the JPQL to get list of data by day, month or year

Tags: eclipse, date, jpql

here i'm having trouble getting list of data by either day , month or year in eclipse. i'm using entity manager to pull info from mySQL database.

i'm creating a web form whereby i can put in the value of the days that i want to view.
this is my Approval table's approval date.

```
@Temporal( TemporalType.DATE)
private Date approvedate;
```

it is auto created in eclipse when i add approval info.

```
     approvedate = new Date();
```

in entity manager i put this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Approval> date(Date fromDate, Date toDate){


    try {
        Query query = entityManager
                .createQuery("SELECT e from Approval e WHERE e.approvedate >= :startdate AND e.approvedate < :enddate");
        query.setParameter("startdate", from);
        query.setParameter( "enddate", to);
        List<Approval> list = query.getResultList();

        return list; 
} catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

and in the bean i put :

```
   import java.text.ParseException;
   import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

private String start;
private String end;
private List<Approval> approvedate;

    public String reportfrom() throws ParseException{
         DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");            
    Date startDate = df.parse(start);
    Date endDate = df.parse(end);
   approvedate= tsm.date(startDate, endDate);

return "success";
```

}

and in my web form i had a box for user to put in the value:

```
    View report of Approval from #{bean.start} and #{bean.end}
```

which is the input value for fromDate and toDate value. --> 01/01/2011, 08/08/2011

but i just could not pull out the data from approval table in mySQL.